# Navigation Bar is in Landscape while View is in Portrait

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar

I am trying to set up some views on the storyboard.

Now I am stuck with displaying the navigation bar in the correct way.

When the corresponding view opens (in Portrait mode) the Navigation Bar opens in Landscape Mode.

How can I set the navigationBar to stick with the screen Orientation and Size?

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure what you mean, are you using the simulator or a Device ? Make sure you add constraints to pin the bar to the top of the view controller or embed your view controller in a navigation controller.